# JOOQ code generator for H2 AUTO_INCREMENT PK with japAnnotations on

Tags: java, sql, h2, jooq

I'm trying to get the jooq code generator working with the below options

```
<generate>
    <pojos>true</pojos>
    <jpaAnnotations>true</jpaAnnotations>
</generate>
```

for table:

```
CREATE TABLE PUBLIC.MSG_LOG (
  ID             BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  IN_DATASOURCE  VARCHAR(63),
  OUT_DATASOURCE VARCHAR(63),
  MSG            VARCHAR(255),
  TIMESTAMP      TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);
```

When i run the code below

```
MsgLogRecord msgLog = dslContext.newRecord(MsgLog.MSG_LOG);
msgLog.setInDatasource(inputSource);
msgLog.setOutDatasource(outputSource);
msgLog.setMsg(Joiner.on("").skipNulls().join(message));
msgLog.setTimestamp(Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
msgLog.store();
```

it throws an error complaining about ID being null, but the same code works if i simply remove `<jpaAnnotations>true</jpaAnnotations>` from jooq's generator config. When i look into the generated classes, seems the MsgLogRecord class is missing a @Generated annotation,

```
/**
 * Getter for <code>PUBLIC.MSG_LOG.ID</code>.
 */
@Id
@Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 19)
public Long getId() {
    return (Long) getValue(0);
}
```

Can any suggest a fix for it?

Comment: Looks like you've already found the solution for your issue - nice catch! You know you can answer your own questions on stack overflow? This way, future visitors who have the same problem will easily find the solution as an answer...

Comment: thanks! I've added an answer incase anyone else ran into the same issue

Comment: Perfect, thanks for documenting this, John. This will certainly be useful for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's an issue with my JPA setting, because I'm using spring boot.

The default hibernate one had spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto property set to create-drop which drops the SEQUENCE object from H2 for some reason...I've set it to none and the code is working now.

In short, **if you're mixing JOOQ code-gen with hibernate JPA, make sure the hibernate.ddl-auto property is set to none**, otherwise it might drop your database objects!